# screen breaking in iPhone x for higher iOS versions.there is no storyboards design done through code

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In my project tabbar(it's like below the navigation bar i have 4 buttons in my tabbar) is going to top after app launches it's happening in iPhone x for higher iOS versions.we are not using storyboards,design done through codeing.check below screenshots.

In the first screenshot  u can't see search bar and above tabs[location,search,deals this is the problem.
 if u observe second one u can see address bar and above tabs for lowerversions it was working.

[This is breaking screen for higher versions above ios11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2RwT.png)

[This is for lower versions design is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDhOk.png)

Comment: I'm not an iOS person, but I cannot see what's broken in one and not the other. Is it colour versus black and white?

Comment: In the first screen u can't see search bar and above tabs[location,search,deals]. if u observe second one u can see address bar and above tabs.

Comment: Please update your question so it will match your screenshots query.

Comment: You need to show the code that sets up the constraints and/or does the layout of the broken parts.